# OSX 10.10 App doesn't get focus or event loop

Tags: objective-c, macos, focus, event-loop

Restarting app development after a 15 year hiatus. Current project is conversion of old windows-type command line utility into interactive OS X windowed app.
I created a view delegate inside main window and can draw and update NSTable view.
The updates are generated in the App's main loop which takes a UDP/TCP stream, parses and updates view via appropriate delegation.

Here's the problem:  When I run the app, the main window does not apparently get
focus (window control buttons on upper left are grey), the Menu created from my .xib is inert, and the window itself does not respond to resizing or to mouse hits inside the table view scroll bars. Also, the mouse pointer is the spinning beachball when over the App's window.

My guess is that I am not providing time to the Objective C run loop for event processing.  I do send a "display" to my window on every iteration of my app loop, but I guess it is not sufficient (Apple is not very clear about what objects get what messages when sending this kind of update message).  Am I on the right track?

Is there a way to let the system Event loop run an iteration each time through my app main loop?

Thanks!

Update: I tried explicitly providing event loop time in my app's main loop with:
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];

There was no apparent change in app behavior.

Comment: Need to see the code for `main`.  That said, you generally get a pointer to `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` set its delegate, and then tell it to `run`.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks!  My Main is generic:                                                          int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}

Comment: To make sure none of my code is screwing things up, I inserted this infinite loop in my AppDelegate as the first thing inside AppicationDidFinishLauncing:                                                                                while (TRUE) {
        [self.window display];
        [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
    }
Again, no change in main window behavior.  I also send a make key and front message to the main window - again no effect, still no focus and inactive main menu.

Comment: So now I believe I must have screwed up the .xib connections somehow as a bare app with just the XCODE generated Xib and no user code should have these behaviors.   My main window has a referencing outlet to the App Delegate. The Appdelegate.h has a outlet property declared. The view inside that Main window has no spec'd outlets or actions.

Comment: If you use `NSApplicationMain` in main.m you need the correctly named Main Nib set in info.plist.  File's Owner for the main[menu] nib should be the application. [See the answer here for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130629/files-owner-and-nsapplication-appdelegate).  I thought you were doing something more non-standard, but it sounds like you've just broken a link in the bog-standard flow.   And it's hard to recover from that.  When I was at your stage, I'd abandon whole projects and dump the code into new ones because the links are vague.

Comment: Also, you should either keep mainmenu.xib and add a window to it that's handled in your app delegate, or if you add a second xib, use an NSWindowController to own it.  It's generally best to keep the main nib as mainmenu.xib.

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that I am not providing time to the Objective C run loop for event processing.

In this case, I recommend you read about [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html), which provides concurrency, allowing the GUI to remain responsive.

There's a good explanation of GCD [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1) and whilst it looks like a large and complicated subject, you'll probably only need a few lines of code to make use of GCD. For example: -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{  
    // do some work    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response TDK!  If you look at my response above, I have basically shorted out all of my code to the simplest possible OS X GUI, just a Xcode generated main window with a View inside. On app launch, the only code running is that loop that runs 0.1 sec slices of the Run loop.  Still no focus obtainable.  I think now that I must have altered, unintentionally the connection to the xib, but all looks like I think it should. The window  ref. outlet is wired to the AppDelegate.  Any thoughts?  I think this most basic level of event processing is supposed to be baked in.

Answer (score 0):

Despite comparing the nibs and connections between my code and a freshly created .xib prototype, i could find no reason for my code to not get focus.

The fix was to move my code guts into the project with a new .xib. 
This works but is unsatisfying