# How to: Blank cocoa application lacking interface builder entry point

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

How do you create a blank mac os cocoa application that lacks a storyboard or MainMenu.xib entry point? Instead, the project loads using good old fashioned code (no interface builder steps at all).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131192/1951992) describes some interesting steps but it isn't specific enough for a newbie of mac os development. For instance, where exactly do I call [NSApp Run]? App Delegate? Main?

Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Comment: And why would you want to do that? What is your goal?

Comment: When I learn something new, I like to pick it apart @rocky. I am interested in how mac os development compares with iOS, which I'm familiar with. I can avoid interface builder on iOS so I would like to know how to do that on mac os.

Comment: I completely get it. I am also not a fan of IB and like to do everything programmatically. I was just asking to see if there was an easier way to accomplish your true goal. Please check my answer. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you need to delete the NSMainNibFile key in Info.plist. Then replace your main.m with the following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // create NSApp object
    NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

    // create your app delegate object
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];

    app.delegate = appDelegate;

    // run the app
    [app run];

    return 0;
}
```

Then you can load your windows and views in your app delegate.

Comment: thanks @rocky a swift setup avoids a manual implementation of main. do you have another solution that doesn't involve main ?